# Write to text files

Tags: c#, text-files, streamwriter

Totally new to this. Depending on which event button I click I need to write to the appropriate text file.  However, the input data writes to the same text file. How do I specify the appropriate text file it writes to and is saved.

The coding, identical apart from the name of the text file, I'm currently using is:

```
private void btnItemAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string sItem;
    string sNumber;

    if (rdoDrinks.Checked == false && rdoConfectionary.Checked == false)
    {
        //Message to remind user to select category
        MessageBox.Show("Please select a category");
        txtItem.Focus();
    }
    {
        {
            if ((rdoDrinks.Checked == true) && (txtItem.Text != "") && (txtItemNumber.Text == ""))

                //Message to remind user to enter a number
                MessageBox.Show("Please input a number");
                txtItemNumber.Focus();

            if ((txtItem.Text != "") && (txtItemNumber.Text != ""))
            {
                //add Item to end of list
                lstItems.Items.Add(string.Format("{0, -15} {1, -20}", txtItem.Text, txtItemNumber.Text));
                txtCount.Text = lstItems.Items.Count.ToString();
                //set focus to the text box
                txtItem.Focus();

                StreamWriter sw = File.AppendText("Drinks.txt");
                {
                    sItem = txtItem.Text;
                    sw.WriteLine(sItem);

                    sNumber = txtItemNumber.Text;
                    sw.WriteLine(sNumber);

                }

                MessageBox.Show("Details have been saved");
                txtItem.Clear();
                txtItemNumber.Clear();

                sw.Close();
            }
            else if ((rdoConfectionary.Checked == true) && (txtItem.Text != "") && (txtItemNumber.Text == ""))
                //Message to remind user to enter a number
                MessageBox.Show("Please input a number");
                txtItemNumber.Focus();

            if ((txtItem.Text != "") && (txtItemNumber.Text != ""))
            {
                //add Item to end of list
                lstItems.Items.Add(string.Format("{0, -15} {1, -20}", txtItem.Text, txtItemNumber.Text));
                txtCount.Text = lstItems.Items.Count.ToString();
                //set focus to the text box
                txtItem.Focus();

                StreamWriter sw = File.AppendText("Confectionary.txt");
                {
                    sItem = txtItem.Text;
                    sw.WriteLine(sItem);

                    sNumber = txtItemNumber.Text;
                    sw.WriteLine(sNumber);
                }

                MessageBox.Show("Details have been saved");
                txtItem.Clear();
                txtItemNumber.Clear();

                sw.Close();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have several issues:

1. You are missing an else after the first `if`.
2. The code below can never end up being `true`.

The two `if` statement collide (the `txtItemNumber.Text` comparison is the problem). Hence you will never end up writing to Drinks.txt:

```
if ((rdoDrinks.Checked == true) && (txtItem.Text != "") && (txtItemNumber.Text == ""))

...

if ((txtItem.Text != "") && (txtItemNumber.Text != ""))
```

Comment: Thank you - after taking your advice I did resolve the issue.  One point though, it always wrote to the Drinks.txt file rather than the Confectionary.txt one.  But that's been sorted.

Comment: @user3387822: Since you are new here, please don't forget to mark the question as answered if the answer was sufficient. Please see the [FAQ#why-vote]